# What is the difference between expired date of the tokens (Google OAuth2) and credentials ?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I want to ask the difference between expired date of the tokens object return from google and when we set in credentials ?

```js
oauth2Client.getToken(code, function (err, tokens) {
  // Now tokens contains an access_token and an optional refresh_token. Save them.
  if (!err) {
    oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
  }
});
```

```js
// Retrieve tokens via token exchange explained above or set them:
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  access_token: 'ACCESS TOKEN HERE',
  refresh_token: 'REFRESH TOKEN HERE'
  // Optional, provide an expiry_date (milliseconds since the Unix Epoch)
  // expiry_date: (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to explain this without the use of Node.   This is pure Oauth.

When you request access from google a credentials object is returned to you it is a Json response and looks something like this.

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_VSBMC2Ga2lhxsTKjVQ_ROco8VbD6h01aj4PcKHLm6qvHbNtn-_BIzXMw",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600,
"refresh_token" : "1/J-3zPA8XR1o_cXebV9sDKn_f5MTqaFhKFxH-3PUPiJ4"
}
```

Expires_in is the amount of time in seconds until the Access token expires.   This is an hour.

Sending an expire date in your request to node isn't going to help you in any way.  Google has decided how long the access token is valid for on their servers this is not something you can change.

Refresh tokens are valid for as long as they are not removed by the user.

Comment: You wrong, I set expired date in setCredentials for 10 second, after 10 second the token doesn't work.

Comment: That is probably something within your NodeJs library.   You are using a generic oauth2Client not one specific built for Google.  The library is expiring it not Google.   If you took the access token and used it without your library it will still work.  Unless someone thought to add a revoke to the library which I serously doubt.

Comment: Yup its in the library https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/261  If you set it to low it will expire it.